# How to stop method from calling themselves recursively?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, recursion, listbox

I have two tables, `employees` and `project`, in `listbox2`, I show all the `employees` and in `listbox1` all the `projects`, now obviously one employee can be involved in many projects and one project could have many employee. So I have this `EmployeeProject` that maps the many to many relation that exists. What I want is, if user click a project name in first listbox, then all employees in that project should be selected in listbox2. Also, when a user clicks a item in listbox2, (an employee) all project of which that employee is a part should be selected in listbox1

**But** If I use ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged event for this process, and select even a single value in listbox2 then it would trigger the SelectedIndexChagned for listbox2, and that would start working by selecting all items in listbox1 that current employee is a part of, but again, as soon as even one item in listbox1 is selected, it would fire up its SelectedIndexChanged event, and it would go on forever like this. So what's the solution of this? So far, I've done this..

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Load the list of employees
            cmd.CommandText =
                "SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID IN(SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeeProject WHERE ProjectID =(SELECT ProjectID FROM Project WHERE ProjectName = '" +
                listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')) ORDER BY EmpId";
            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            // right now, I am doing this to escape this recursive loop, but thats not what I want
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
            }
            rdr.Close();

            this.AutoScroll = true;
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Load the list of projects

            cmd.CommandText =
               "SELECT ProjectName FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID IN(SELECT ProjectID FROM EmployeeProject WHERE EmpId=(SELECT EmpId FROM Employee WHERE EmpName= '" +
                listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')) ORDER BY ProjectID";
            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            // again, I don't want to clear, but select all those employee in listbox1 that are involved in this selected project, but can't do it because it would cause infinite recursion of these
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
            listBox2.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
            }
            rdr.Close();

            this.AutoScroll = true;
        }
```

So? What should I do to achieve what I want to achieve? And how would I avoid that recursion? I know this way also works what I just showed, but I don't want to clear up and show up again, (this might confuse a simple user). I want for each selection, values corresponding to that selection be selected in other listbox (without causing recursion of course!). How do I do it?

*EDIT* I don't know how can I select multiple items in listbox programmatically, so if you could tell that, it would be great!

Comment: I'm assuming this is winforms. Am I right?

Comment: Why dont you unbind the event from the other textbox before changing the selected items then after its selected rebind it.

Comment: Isn't there anything in your `sender` or `args` parameters that you can use to tell apart the two cases (when selection is made by the user and when selection is made programmatically)?

Comment: @CyberDude
I don't know. May be? Haven't tried yet, will try and get back to you :)

Comment: I hate to be overly pedantic, but I don't believe this is really recursion. This is a multi-party infinite loop. Your events are pinging back and forth, but they're not calling themselves.

Comment: You may want to look into using parameterized queries, rather than just pasting the text of your listboxes into the query, otherwise you run the risk of SQL injection (depends on where the data in your listboxes comes from).

Comment: @Razort4x dont forget to accept an answer if any is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the selected items of one listbox, you could temporarily disable the events on the other.  For example:

```
// Store the event handlers in private member variables.
private System.EventHandler selectedEmployeeChanged = new System.EventHandler(this.lbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged); 

private void lbProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Remove your event so that updating lbEmployees doesn't cause
        // lbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged to get fired.
        lbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged -= selectedEmployeeChanged;

        // other event handler logic
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure that the handler on lbEmployees is re-added,
        // even if an exception was encountered.
        lbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged += selectedEmployeeChanged;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have renamed your listBoxes (and the associated events) to be more readable.  As per your description, `listBox1` is now `lbEmployees` and `listBox2` is now `lbProjects`.

As for programatically selecting multiple items, if you know the index for each one, you could use the [ListBox.SetSelected Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected).  For example:

```
listBox1.SetSelected(1, true);
listBox1.SetSelected(3, true);
```

causes listBox1 to select the items at 1 and 3.

In your case, I would recomend only using the queries to get what values to select (not clearing your listboxes and then just adding back the values that should be selected).  Below is my suggestion for how you would rewrite one of your handlers:

```
// Store the event handlers in private member variables.
private System.EventHandler selectedEmployeeChanged = new System.EventHandler(this.lbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged); 

private void lbProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare this outside of try so that we can close it in finally
    DbDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        // Remove your event so that updating lbEmployees doesn't cause
        // lbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged to get fired.
        lbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged -= selectedEmployeeChanged;
        // Deselect all items in lbEmployees
        lbEmployees.ClearSelected();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProjectName FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID IN(SELECT ProjectID FROM EmployeeProject WHERE EmpId=(SELECT EmpId FROM Employee WHERE EmpName= '@EmpName')) ORDER BY ProjectID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", lbProjects.SelectedItem.ToString());
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // For each row returned, find the index of the matching value
        // in lbEmployees and select it.
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            int index = lbEmployees.FindStringExact(rdr.GetString(0));
            if(index != ListBox.NoMatches)
            {
                lbEmployees.SetSelected(index, true);
            }
        }

        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure that the reader gets closed, even if an exception ocurred
        if(reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        // Ensure that the handler on lbEmployees is re-added,
        // even if an exception was encountered.
        lbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged += selectedEmployeeChanged;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you may want to look into using a JOIN operator in your query string, rather than multiple nested SELECTS.

Answer (score 5):

There is a design pattern called Balking, I think it applies here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern

The idea is to introduce an auxiliary state variable to control the operation:

```
  private bool doesProcessing { get; set; }

  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanging( ... )
  {
     // signal the beginning of processing
     if ( doesProcessing ) 
        return;
     else
        doesProcessing = true; 

     try
     {
        // your logic goes here
     }
     finally
     {
        // signal the end of processing
        doesProcessing = false;
     }
  }
```

and the same for listBox2.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the attached event to one of the controls when you are in the other, before doing any modifications.
then reattach at the end.

Comment: But I don't know how can I select multiple items. I tried, but didn't worked out, could you provide the code to select multiple items?

Comment: Isn't it a bool property of the list control?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the OP code (if working as OP expect) contains a problem.
Suppose you fill the two lists with all possible values.
Then, when the user clicks on one item, the second list is emptied and filled only with the item linked to the other list. But clicking between the two list could remove forever one or more item from the other list. It is better to leave the two list filled and trying to highlight the line of the corresponding items

For example (supposing ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple or MultiExtended)

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
........
try
{
   ......
   // Remove the event handler, do your selection, No event on the listbox2 will be fired....
   listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);

   // Do not remove the items , instead clear previous selection
   listBox2.ClearSelected(); 

   while (rdr.Read()) 
   { 
       int index = listBox2.FindString(rdr.GetString(0), -1);
       if(index != -1) listBox2.SetSelected(index, true)); 
   } 
   ....
}
finally
{
    // before exit, reapply the event handler 
    listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
}
```

of course you need to be sure to reapply the event, so use a try/finally block
The same approach will be valid to stop the event firing for listBox1 when you fill it in the listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged event,

Answer (score 0):

Have one eventMask integer variable and use the pattern below to protect your event each other.

Using a bool as suggested in another answer is enough for this scenario. However, I prefer to use an integer rather than a bool : it can handle nested and stacked events calls correctly.

It is particularly useful when I have to deal with selection/deselection events in treeviews and listviews for example.

```
int eventMask = 0;

void items_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) // for example...
{
    if (eventMask > 0)
        return;

    try
    {
        eventMask++;

        // processing
        // it happens some other events can be called. Including this one.
    }
    finally 
    {
        // put this in finally, so there is no lock risk
        eventMask--;
    }
}
```